# Automatically add columns and formula then fill-down

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a routine which automatically adds new columns and fills them out. I have the following codes in VBA to automatise the process,

```
Sub AddHeader()
    Worksheets(1).Range("Y1").Formula = "Alder"
    Worksheets(1).Range("Z1").Formula = "Premier"
End Sub


Sub AddFormula()
    Dim Formulas(1 To 2) As Double
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Formulas(1) = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365,25)"
        Formulas(2) = "=IF(L2="";0;L2)"
        .Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = Formulas
        .Range("Y:Z").NumberFormat = "General"
    End With
End Sub

Sub FillColumnY()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("Y2:Y" & LastRow).FillDown
End Sub

Sub FillColumnZ()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("Z2:Z" & LastRow).FillDown
End Sub
```

My Problem is the `AddFormula()` program, which gives the following error-message:

> "Compile error - Data or member could not be found"

When I try to compile the `AddFormula()` manually, I get the following error:

> "Run time error '9', Subscript out of range"

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get an error first off in that procedure using `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` - you haven't told it which worksheet - it's trying to look at all sheets.
Try `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`

Next you've defined Formulas as a Double - which will only accept numbers.
You then try and assign the text string `"=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365,25)"` to it.

Try something like this:

```
 Public Sub All_Together()

    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("Y1:Z1") = Array("Alder", "Premier")
        '.Range("Y2").Formula = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365.25)"
        '.Range("Z2").Formula = "=IF(L2="""",0,L2)" 'Note doubling up of quotes in string.

        .Range("Y2").Formula = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365,25)"
        .Range("Z2").Formula = "=IF(L2="""";0;L2)"

        'If there's no data on the sheet LastRow will throw an error.
        On Error Resume Next
            LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
            If LastRow = 0 Then LastRow = 1
        On Error GoTo 0

        .Range("Y2:Z" & LastRow).FillDown
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: .Range("Y2").Formula = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365,25)"
        .Range("Z2").Formula = "=IF(L2="""";0;L2)"    gives an error by "1104 Application defined or user defined erre"

Comment: @JonathanKiersch That'll be a locality thing - OP uses 365,25 instead of 365.25 and `;` in the IF function instead of `,`.  Comment out those lines, and put back in the one's I've commented out and it should work.  Saying that - VBA makes the conversion I think, so yeah - you're right.  Just use the commented out lines. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

`Dim Formulas(1 To 2) As Double`

in

`Dim Formulas(1 To 2) As Variant`

But this is not the reason of your error. It would show 'Type mismatch`.
You input strings in the array. No matter what the formula result would be...

Than,

`With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` does not have any meaning for VBA, in this context and this line is problematic, raising the error in discussion.

It must be `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)`, or `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("My Sheet")`, or even `With ActiveSheet`...

And, if you would try to use it for copying the array in **all sheets** this must be done in a different way. I will show you how, if this was your intention...

Supplementary, the formula in this way `"=IF(L2="";0;L2)"` may not work as you need. Even if, according to localization, the formula separator is ";", it is good to use `"=IF(L2="",0,L2)"`. Excel **will make the appropriate conversion** and in case of using the workbook on a computer with comma separator, no error will be raised. You may also receive an error at the line `.Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = Formulas`, because of that. You can  solve it, doing as I recommended above...

In fact, your function must look like this:

```
Sub AddFormula()
    Dim Formulas(1 To 2) As Variant
    With ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Formulas(1) = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365.25)"
        Formulas(2) = "=IF(L2="""",0,L2)"
        .Range("Y2:Z2").Formula = Formulas
        .Range("Y:Z").NumberFormat = "General"
    End With
End Sub
```

You receive an error, because both of your formula strings contain errors:  `365,25` must be `365.25`. Otherwise, VBA thinks it is another list separation (`,`) and an error would occur and each double quotes character must be doubled in a string. I mean `"=IF(L2="",0,L2)"` must become `"=IF(L2="""",0,L2)"`.

Now, when I am sure that the above function will work, I will post another one able to fill (at once) all the columns you need to fill them down in a separate step:

```
Sub AddFormulaBis()
    Dim Formulas(1 To 2) As Variant, lastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet 'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        lastRow = .Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
        Formulas(1) = "=INT((TODAY()-J2)/365.25)"
        Formulas(2) = "=IF(L2="""",0,L2)"
        .Range("Y2:Z" & lastRow).Formula = Formulas
        .Range("Y2:Z" & lastRow).NumberFormat = "General"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: At what line? Can you edit your question and post the code you used, please?

Comment: @Jonathan Kiersch: I edited my answer and placed the function as it must be. Please test it and send some feedback...

Comment: This approach has worked now, however, when filling down, it fills way more cells than it should. How can I successfully define last row in the macro?

Comment: @Jonathan Kiersch: As you can see, the code define the range according to J:J column. This is the one I found being referred in the formula...

Comment: @Jonathan Kiersch: I took it like a challenge... But, in such cases, when an answer solved your problem, we tick the left code side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for the same issue will know that the code worked. And voting it up will certainly not kill anybody, too... :)